# Detecting closed loop in a 2D array pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

Let's assume that you get the following array:

```js
foo = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
]
```

How can I determine if the pattern of 1s is a closed loop? I have struggled with this for a few days. I have tried a recursive loop to find neighbors and words, but when you have a more complex pattern it won't work, for example:

```js
foo = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
]
```

Do someone have a magic algorithm to solve this ? :(

Comment: You probably want to implement `Dijkstra's Algorithm` and iterate through your array as nodes. Then test to see if you have returned to your starting location.

Comment: Sorry, do you want the second example to count as having a closed loop? Also, do you need zeros within the loop or will four 1s in a square count?

Comment: I could see the "Flood Fill" algorithm working in this case, as in the bucket fill in a paint program. If you "fill" a region of 0's and it doesn't spill out of the edges of the array, it must be closed. You would have to try every separate region of 0's though.

Comment: yes the second example a "magic" function should return a array with the coordinates of only the 1 that is a closed loop, my recursive function can make this with the first example, but with the second when it find 2 neighbors the function assume one direction and continue the loop, but like in the second example, it could get wrong direction and not closed the loop, its complex and my english is bad 
I trie'd the Dijkstra's Algorithm but it works for polygons, i dont know if it fit for this problem, and flood fill will expend too much of cpu Thank you guys wanna hear more ideias

Comment: You could count the numbers of extremities of a loop and the number of fork. If the loop is closed, there will be as many forks as there is extremities (could be more)

Comment: Could your array contain more than one loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Dagrooms said, try to find 1(s) with only one adjacent 1. Code looks like:

```
function isValid1(x,y){
  return (foo[x-1][y] + foo[x+1][y] + foo[x][y-1] + foo[x][y + 1])>1;
}

function validLoop(){
  for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      if(foo[i][j] === 1 && !isValid1(i,j)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

where rows and columns are the 2d array size.

**UPDATE**

This will return true if there is at least one closed loop:

```
function numTouching1(x,y){
  return foo[x - 1][y] + foo[x + 1][y] + foo[x][y - 1] + foo[x][y + 1];
}

function validLoop(){
  var n = 0, x = 0; // x is current point's number of touching 1 and n is total
  for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      if(foo[i][j] === 1) {
        x = numTouching1(i, j) - 2;
        if(x === -1 || x === 1 || x === 2){
          n += x;
        } 
      }
    }
  }
  return n > -1;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AdminXVII/b0f7th5d/

**UPDATE 2**
Extract the loop(s):

```
function numTouching1(x,y){
  return foo[x - 1][y] + foo[x + 1][y] + foo[x][y - 1] + foo[x][y + 1];
}

function extractLoop(){
  for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      if(foo[i][j] === 1 && numTouching1(i, j) === 1){
          foo[i][j] = 0;
          extractLoop();break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AdminXVII/b0f7th5d/7/

**UPDATE 3**

This is to threat if there's more than one loop, thougth for one loop it's slower.

```
function numTouching1(x, y) {
    return foo[x - 1][y] + foo[x + 1][y] + foo[x][y - 1] + foo[x][y + 1];
}

function extractLoop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (foo[i][j] === 1 && numTouching1(i, j) === 1) {
                foo[i][j] = 0;
                extractLoop(); break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function validLoop(){
  extractLoop();
  for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      if(foo[i][j] === 1 && numTouching1(i,j) == 2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AdminXVII/w7zcgpyL/

**UPDATE 4**

Safer `numTouching1()` method:

```
function numTouching1(x, y) {
    return ((x > 0) ? foo[x - 1][y] : 0) + ((x < rows-1) ? foo[x + 1][y] : 0) + ((y > 0) ? foo[x][y - 1] : 0) + ((y < columns-1) ? foo[x][y + 1] : 0);
}
```

Modified previous JSFiddle

Comment: It will return 100 times true or false?

Comment: @Thiago Frias No, since `return` is only called once per function call.

Comment: It will return true if it's a closed loop and false if it's not

Comment: Could you set up a test case. I get false for both patterns http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/d01o9jk8/

Comment: @K3N Thank you, I forgot to initialize n so it was always returning false. See my post for the JSFiddle test

Comment: @adminXVII I think the fiddle in the answer is missing the -2 in the numTouching1() function at the end, it still returns false with that version. I updated my own fiddle and get true with n initialized though: http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/d01o9jk8/2/

Comment: @K3N No the code was good. Moved the `-2` from `numTouching1()` to `validLoop()`. It was returning false because it was false: I had changed a 1 to a 0, so it wasn't closed. Changed it, however, to an other example

Comment: Wow, the code is perfect, and thank you so much, you think is hard to get the index or coordinates of the 1s that is only on the closed loop or is a whole new thing ?

Comment: @Thiago Frias a simple way I see to do this is simply to delete 1 that are touching to one 1. That way, at the end, you would have a cleared array with only the loop(s). Trying to do some code to acheive this.

Comment: Thank you \o/ with a little modification now i can get the loop coordinates, i make a change to check if the 1 is on the border take a look https://jsfiddle.net/L1wqrzbd/ and again thank you /o/

Comment: so with this array:
https://jsfiddle.net/m142rtwe/
is returning false :/ do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @admin XVII i think a paste the wrong array look now https://jsfiddle.net/7r87sqyn/ on debuging a look that the var n become -4 when having other 1 that is touching other 1 oO

Comment: @ThiagoFrias you copy-paste my JSFiddle... try pasting your array here.

Comment: \o/ ITS ALIVE!!! thank you @admin XVII now with your black magic i can continue with my game, hope this help other folks too o/